# Ler em outra activity uma variavel que é atualizada no MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Tenho uma função que é executada a cada segundo. Essa função envia uma requisição de informação via *socket* para um dispositivo. Essa informação é recebida em uma `AsyncTask` que faz os cálculos e atualiza algumas variáveis que estão na `MainActivity` e são exibidas em tela.

O problema é que também preciso exibir o conteúdo dessas variáveis em uma outra *activity*. E esse conteúdo tem que acompanhar as alterações que a variável recebe a cada segundo.

Tenho que usar a mesma variável que está na e `MainActivity` não posso abrir um novo *socket* pois o primeiro continua recebendo os dados mesmo com outra *activity* sendo exibida.

Answer (score 4):

Essa não é a melhor abordagem.

Se tem uma operação(função) que é executada periodicamente e cujo resultado quer obter em mais de um local da sua aplicação, não a faça numa Activity.
Uma Activity não deve depender de outra para executar a sua função.

O Android disponibiliza a classe [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) para casos desse tipo.
Num Serviço as operações são executadas de forma independente dos outros componentes da aplicação, no entanto é possível a comunicação entre eles.

Neste seu caso, uma possível abordagem é usar um [*Bound Service*(Serviço vinculado)](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html):

> (...)Um serviço vinculado permite que componentes (como atividades) sejam vinculados ao serviço, enviem solicitações, recebam respostas e até estabeleçam comunicação entre processos (IPC)....
>   <sub>(documentação Android, [Serviços vinculados](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html))</sub>

Exemplo que usa um serviço para calcular a raiz quadrada.

**SqrCalculatorService.java**

```
public class SqrCalculatorService extends Service {

    public static final int SQR_MSG = 0;
    public static final String SQR_RESULT = "sqrResult";

    public SqrCalculatorService() {
    }

    public static Intent makeIntent(Context context){
        return new Intent(context, SqrCalculatorService.class);
    }
    private final Messenger mCalculateMessenger = new Messenger(new CalculateHandler());

    private static class CalculateHandler extends Handler{

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            switch (msg.what) {
                case SQR_MSG:
                    double sqr = calculate(msg.arg1);
                    replyToCaller(msg.replyTo, sqr);
                    break;
                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }

        private static double calculate(int arg1) {
            return Math.sqrt(arg1);
        }

        private static void replyToCaller(Messenger msg, double sqr) {
            Message reply = Message.obtain(null, SQR_MSG);
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putDouble(SQR_RESULT, sqr);
            reply.setData(data);
            try {
                msg.send(reply);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mCalculateMessenger.getBinder();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Messenger mServiceMessenger = null;
    private TextView tvResultado;
    private EditText edValor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvResultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResultado);
        edValor = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edValor);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(mServiceMessenger == null){
            bindService(SqrCalculatorService.makeIntent(this),
                        srvConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        unbindService(srvConnection);
        super.onStop();
    }

    private ServiceConnection srvConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {

            mServiceMessenger = new Messenger(iBinder);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {

            mServiceMessenger = null;
        }
    };

    final Messenger mResultMessenger = new Messenger(new ResultHandler());

    private class ResultHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case SqrCalculatorService.SQR_MSG:
                    Bundle data = msg.getData();
                    displaySQRResult(data);
                    break;
                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
        private void displaySQRResult(Bundle data) {
            double sqr = data.getDouble(SqrCalculatorService.SQR_RESULT);
            tvResultado.setText(Double.toString(sqr));
        }
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v){
        int value = Integer.parseInt(edValor.getText().toString());
        Message msg = Message.obtain(null, SqrCalculatorService.SQR_MSG, value, 0);
        msg.replyTo = mResultMessenger;
        try {
            mServiceMessenger.send(msg);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbValor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Valor a calcular: "/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edValor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lbValor"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbValor"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lbValor"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbResultado"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lbValor"
        android:text="Resultado: "
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResultado"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lbResultado"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbResultado"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lbResultado"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lbResultado"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Calcular raiz quadrada"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Registo do serviço no *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<application>
    ....
    ....
    <service
        android:name=".SqrCalculatorService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
    </service>
</application>
```